# I have a ThinkPad T60 with Ubuntu 13.04 and WIFI is inoperable--anyone know how to get it working?

Tags: 13.04, wireless, thinkpad

The network device is identified as "hardware switch disabled", but I know of no such switch.  I am part of a volunteer group (KINfolk) which loans out laptops to patients and parents at Children's hospitals in the Nemours (DuPont family) community.  Some company donated several T60s and at least on T61 recently and I am trying to determine if there is any value in putting Ubuntu on the machines.  I was able to install Windows 7 on the test machine, but it is also unable to see any WIFI, although it claims the adapter is "enabled".  Any advice is welcome!

Comment: try `sudo rfkill unblock all` and see what you get. Also could you paste the output of `rfkill list` and `lspci -vnn | grep Network` ?

Answer (score 9):

The ThinkPad T60, and T60P do have a hardware switch.  See image below. (Image compliments of Lenovo).

[image]

To enable WiFi the switch must be pushed to the right side, a green dot should be visible.

Comment: This worked like a charm!  I'd like to know what part of the Lenovo website you got the picture from--I didn't have any luck finding it.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is the [URL](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-62813).